# get black screen when switch view controller with XCode storyboard

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xcode-storyboard, xcode4.3

I am writing a simple app with a tab bar controller, and two tabs. The first tab will switch to another UITableViewController, which works fine. The second tab should switch to a view controller, which inherits from UIViewController, but it just shows black screen.

And I hook on ViewDidLoad, ViewDidAppear functions in the destination UIViewController, I found it is loaded well. But it just shows me a black screen. Any idea of what happen here? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the empty implementation of `- (void)loadView` from your viewController. 
Since you load your view from a nib (in your case storyboard) you don't need to construct your view in code (i.e. implement `loadView`).

It's there because of a bug (10887149) in the Xcode view controller template.

EDIT: This bug is fixed in Xcode 4.3.2. The template does no longer contain `- (void)loadView`

Comment: you are right, after I comment out loadView, it works well now. thanks!